# Stripe v3 and SAQ-A

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm working with Stripe API and moving from v2 to v3.

I need to confirm that this form is SAQ-A (not SAQ-AEP)

Full codes: http://jsfiddle.net/xz1db74n/

HTML:

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<body>
  <form action="//httpbin.org/post" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" />
    <div class="group">
      <label>
        <span>Card number</span>
        <div id="card-number-element" class="field"></div>
      </label>
      <label>
        <span>Expiry date</span>
        <div id="card-expiry-element" class="field"></div>
      </label>
      <label>
        <span>CVC</span>
        <div id="card-cvc-element" class="field"></div>
      </label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Pay $25</button>
    <div class="outcome">
      <div class="error"></div>
      <div class="success">
        Success! Your Stripe token is <span class="token"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you shared doesn't really detail how you are integrating exactly. The only reference is loading Stripe.js v3 without showing how you use it. Overall though, as long as you use Stripe [Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js#elements) and load the page over HTTPS then you will meet the requirements for SAQ A. This covered in details in Stripe's documentation here: https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#validating-pci-compliance